# Selenium Webdriver - How to handle Facebook alter dialog after Login

Tags: selenium, testing, webdriver

[image]

This is the image which is showing pop up when I login into facebook. 
The question is how should I dismiss the pop up with the help of Webdriver in Java.

I have tried with alert/popup but both are not working.

Comment: Besides you completely breaking the image links could you post the code itself in the question as text?

Comment: @Dimplepatel You may like to remove the FB credentials ASAP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not alert or popup. This is chrome notification which can be disabled by **ChromeOptions**.

Use below code snippet to disable all notifications.

```
ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
options.addArguments("--disable-notifications");
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","path/to/driver/exe");
WebDriver driver =new ChromeDriver(options);
```